# Possible strict violation - using prototype method for JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am getting the following issue with my code. I have a function that will take product data and then return it. We have many options on what we can sort the data on (for example price, name, data, stock levels, etc). Now I pass my data (which is in a JSON format) and depending on the option that is set as an argument I perform the data transform, however I get the following error when I run my code: `Possible strict violation.`

This is my function to sort the data:

```
// this is how i call the function, the data argument is the JSON data and formatting options are set in an object literal - this determines the data by name

dataSort(data, {'name':'product name'});

function dataSort(d, obj) {
// we do lots of stuff then later in the function   
for (var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(key === 'name'){
                d = this.getProductByName(d, obj[key]); // This line produces the error
            }
        }
    }
    return d;
}

dataSort.prototype.getProductByName = function(data, val){
    // do stuff the return data
    return data;
};
```

Now I was alway taught to use the prototype when creating internal methods on functions, why am I getting my error? What am I doing wrong? Should I use a private method or an internal method using `this.getProductByName = function(){}` Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not creatin an internal function. You should use the prototype only if you have **shared** methods on **instances** of a constructor - neither of which you have here.

Comment: you have `dataSort` and `datasort`.

Comment: What browser throws a "***possible** strict violation*"? Either it is a violation or not. Please create an [executable example including sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will produce the error.

Comment: @ Daniel A. White - thanks for the type, fixed that now

Comment: @ Bergi - JSHint is throwing the error in Grunt.

Comment: @ Bergi -  do you recommend a private variable like var getProductByName = function(data, val){};

Comment: @MarkSandman: Then don't say that your code was "run", but that it was "linted". Well, indeed this will not run, but the JSHint error is confusing - there are more fundamental issues with the code. Yes, a local variable with that function would be perfectly fine. You don't have a constructor, and no instances of anything, so you cannot use prototypes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to define private helper functions is to use a closure.

```
var datasort = (function () {
    var getProductByName = function (data, val){
        // do stuff
        return data;
    };

    return function datasort(d, obj) {
        var key;

        // do lots of stuff ...
        return getProductByName(d, obj.name);
    };
}());
```

`getProductByName` is now only visible to the inner `datasort` function (which gets assigned to a variable of the same name).

The effect of the closure is that `getProductByName` is created only once, instead of with every call of `datasort` (that would be the case if you moved `var getProductByName ...` into `function datasort`).